# Does aws "network load balancer" has an http/https addess?

Tags: amazon-elb

I'm trying to call my AWS Load balancer which is of type Network Load Balancer with http using its `A` address. Does AWS Nework Load Balancer support http call, I mean if I call it using http://network-load-balancer-A-name/path, will it forward the request to associated targets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [AWS Network Load balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/introduction.html) operates at Layer 4 of the [OSI stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model), it does not know what Http is as that is something at the Application layer or layer 7 of the OSI stack.

If the [listener](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-listeners.html) of the AWS Network Load Balancer is configured to listen on Port 80 and is configured to forward traffic from [port 80](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) to the [target](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-target-groups.html) then yes, setting up a A record with an [Alias](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html) in [Amazon Route53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/) will forward to the Network Load Balancer then on to the targets. Without the Alias setting in Route53 or using something else and not Route53 would require the IP address of the Load Balancer.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me to call load-balancer correctly, located the corrsponding A record in Amazon Route53 pointing to Network Load Balancer and calling it worked like charm.